# How to integrate CKEditor 4 easy image into Angular 6?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Recently I have tried to work with CKEditor 4 to upload image for my website. However, I cannot find any solutions on the Internet that are about adding `Easy Image` add-on to my project because I have installed CKEditor4 via terminal. What I have found is that we need to change `config.js` inside the root folder of CKEditor but I cannot find any `config.js` files installed by terminal. Can someone help me solve this problem ? I would really appreciate.

[I cannot find config.js in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPuHI.png)

[But I can find it if I download directly from CKEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHGGT.png)

Comment: Inside the root folder where ? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use CKEditor with angular is by placing this tag in index.html

```
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And use [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor)

Example app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-ckeditor)

To add EasyImage modify the config

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ckeConfig = {
      allowedContent: false,
      extraPlugins: 'divarea,easyimage',
      forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
      cloudServices_tokenUrl:'YOUR_TOKEN_URL'
    };
  }
```

available config options [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html)

Comment: Can you help me with adding Easy Image add-on in CKEditor 4, which helps upload files from your computer ?

Comment: Modified the answer for this

Comment: Where should I place the `ckeConfig` ? Is it true to put it inside `<ckeditor ` tag?

Comment: did you see the sample? app.component.ts and app.component.html ? inspect them

Comment: Thanks a lot @SGalea, I fix this problem now, but could you tell me where I can customise my `cloudServices_tokenUrl` where it stores my images ?

Comment: Updated the answer config should be like that

Comment: I really appriciate your help, thanks a lot :)